# Changing Mercurial "Default" Parent URL

Tags: mercurial

Let's say I have a Mercurial repository and I'm pulling from a default parent URL (the source I cloned it from).

Now I want to change the default parent URL (hostname change, or it was copied to another machine, etc.). Is there a way to do this, or do I have to re-clone from the new URL?

Answer (score 150, accepted):

You can even add multiple entries in the [paths] section of your .hg/hgrc file.

```
[paths]
default = /repo_store/hg/project1
sandbox = /repo_store/hg/project1_experimental
```

And then can specify its alias in the mercurial commands. default repo need not be specified but others have to be like,

```
hg in            # check incoming changes from default repo
hg in default    # check incoming changes from default repo
hg in sandbox    # check incoming changes from sandbox repo
hg pull sandbox  # pull changes from sandbox repo
```

Answer (score 54):

I just found the answer to my own question. Edit the `.hg/hgrc` file in the repository, change the `default` setting under the `[paths]` section. Simple!

Answer (score 3):

#### Example of setting default BitBucket repository for Mercurial push and pull.

Normally we can use

```
$ hg push https://bitbucket.org/username/com.example.app
```

But if we want to use `$ hg push` without the repository URL we must add the URL to the file $REPO/.hg/hgrc. We add the following contents:

```
[paths]
default = https://bitbucket.org/username/com.example.app
```

Regarding your question, just set the `default` path to new URL.