# How to break connection between a clone repository and its parent

Tags: mercurial

I have some (local) repositories, an original and some clones.  The original repository has been corrupted so I'd like to get rid of it and use one of the clones as the master for future development.

Is there a better way to break the connection between the new master and the original repository than simply deleting the `default` entry in the `[paths]` section of that clone's hgrc?

Similarly, in the other clones, can I simply change the `default` entry in their hgrc files' `[paths]` section to point to the new master repository?

Comment: What you're suggesting works great, but Martin's solution below, just move a good repo where the bad one is/was, is the least effort solution.

Comment: @Ry4an: in Martin's answer, I thought "delete" and "replace" referred to the entries in the .hg/hgrc, but I like your interpretation better. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All clones are independent, but they remember where they were cloned from. As you have found out, this is stored in the `.hg/hgrc` file. You are free to edit this file as you like. You can even [add more paths](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgrc.5.html#paths) if you want.

So in your case you just delete the original repository and replace it with a good clone.

Answer (score 1):

The idea is either:

- to define a new default path in the `paths` section
- or to define a new path (see this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/860761/changing-mercurial-default-parent-url))

But in both cases, that involves modifying the `hgrc` files.