# How set the default repository

Tags: mercurial

How can I set default remote repository for mercurial local repository?

Comment: Can you explain?  Are you referring to the default URL when you execute `hg pull`?

Comment: Yes, I get message "repository default not found" after execute "hg pull".

Comment: duplicate of [Changing Mercurial “Default” Parent URL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/860761/changing-mercurial-default-parent-url) ?

Answer (score 165, accepted):

It's in the .hg/hgrc file.

```
[paths]
default = https://myserver/hg/repo1
default:pushurl = /home/me/mytestrepo
```

Comment: Thanks. But may be there is any way to set it from command prompt?

Comment: @demas, yes: `echo -e "[paths]\ndefault = http://myserver/hg/repo1\ndefault-push = ../mytestrepo" >> .hg/hgrc`

Comment: Yeah, tonfa's right on both counts. You do it by editing a file and if you don't want to pop open an editor you could do it by shell redirect.  There's no 'set' command.

Comment: The default-push line makes hg push hanging at "...repository locked by hostname:xxxx"

Comment: That means that a process running on machine *hostname* connected on port *xxxx* has locked your repository. It has nothing to do with the `default-push` line.

Comment: For anyone new, Mercurial has added a new `--edit` option for the `config` command, which will open your config files in an editor. It's not as simple as `hg config set default=http://myserver/hg/repo1`, but it's a start.

Comment: @demas if you clone it from the original repo, it will set the path correctly--that's the only sane way to do it from the command line.

Comment: My .hg directory has no hgrc file.

Comment: Just create one with the above contents. There's nothing magical about them.

Comment: `man hgrc` says that nowadays (9 years later:-) it should be `default:pushurl` instead of default-push.