# Changing the url hg pull uses

Tags: mercurial

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Changing Mercurial “Default” Parent URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/860761/changing-mercurial-default-parent-url)

Initially our application was at

http://ourserver.com/webapp

now it is at

http://outserver.com/dev

Because I did an hg clone "http://ourserver.com/webapp" hg pull now uses "http://ourserver.com/webapp".  How can I change it so hg pull uses "http://ourserver.com/dev" other than explicitly using hg pull http://ourserver.com/webapp or re-cloning the repo?

Comment: are you using a console or something like tortoiseHG?

Answer (score 25):

You can just edit .hg/hgrc

```
[paths]
default = https://yoururl.com/dev-repo-name
```

Comment: The line will currently say: `default = http://ourserver.com/webapp`