# How to update URL of the existing cloned repository in Mercurial

Tags: version-control, mercurial

I am using mercurial for Source Control. I have cloned a repository from address

> http://xyz/

Now my repository address is changed to https instead of http.

> https://xyz/

How can update this in existing cloned repository so I can pull the latest changes, without cloning the entire repository again?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Changing Mercurial "Default" Parent URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/860761/changing-mercurial-default-parent-url)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just go to settings for the repository. Click on edit file
it should show something like below

```
[paths]
default = http://xyz
```

Change it to https and it should resolve the issue